# (VBA) Square equalities - Sub or function not defined

Tags: vba, excel

I'm facing some problems with my exercise test in uni, but after editing some code it seems like something is wrong there.

```
Public Function Uzd(x) As String
    If x = 1 Or x = 2 Then
        Uzd = (2 * x + 3) / sqrt(x ^ 2 + 3 * x + 2)
    Else
        Uzd = "Incorrect data"
    End If

End Function
```

After running code I get - Sub or function not defined

Comment: `sqrt` should be `Sqr`.

Comment: It seems you are confusing the C++ [sqrt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1xa99e6.aspx) function with VBA's [sqr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263367.aspx) function.

Comment: Public sub Uzd(x as Integer) as Integer
If x = 1 Or x = 2 Then
Uzd = (2 * x + 3) / sqrt(x ^ 2 + 3 * x + 2)
Else
 msgbox "Incorrect data"
End If
End sub

Comment: @Ary a `Sub` procedure can't return a value, so it can't be `As Integer`. Also you're still using the non-existing `sqrt` function which is OP's exact problem here, and you're introducing presentation concerns by making OP's function bring up a `MsgBox`, which makes the function impossible to write unit tests for.

Comment: Sorry, I could not edit my comment.

Comment: But OP function returns both integer and a String according to his condition, while the function is defined as a string function... An error should be occurred, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Ary no. The numeric result will be implicitly converted to a `String`. Parameter `x` is also implicitly declared as a `Variant` and should be an explicit `Integer` or `Long`, and the function should be raising a runtime error about the invalid parameter instead of returning a magic string and requiring the caller to verify every result against the `"Incorrect data"` string literal.

Answer (score 0):

The function you're trying to use is located in the `VBA` type library, in the `Math` module:

[image: Object Browser]

You can avoid such typos by using IntelliSense and fully-qualifying the global-scope functions you use:

```
Uzd = (2 * x + 3) / Math.Sqr(x ^ 2 + 3 * x + 2)
```

[image: IntelliSense]